# Finding a loop invariant

Tags: loop-invariants

the following pseudo code returns the nth Fibonacci number:

```
 if n = 0 then
    return 0
 a ← 1
 b ← 1
 for i = 1 to n − 1 do
     c ← b − i
     b ← c + a
     a ← c + 2*i + 1
 return b
```

I am trying to find any loop invariant for the variables a and b, (as i understand it has to be valid before and after the loop, but i can't seem to be able to come up with anything, except maybe `b >= i`, but I'm not sure that counts as an invariant). As far as I get it, simply saying `b = b - i + a` wouldn't really mean anything. Any help on the subject would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try finding the values of $a,b,c$ in terms of $i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we already know, the loop iteratively calculates the nth Fibonacci number, so it naturally follows that the loop invariant should contain $b = \mathsf{fib}(i)$ condition.
But that is not sufficient for us, because the computation depends on the variable `a`, and we don't need `c`, because it is initialized in the loop body.

The line `b ← c + a` actually gives us a hint as to what the condition on `a` should we impose: after this line $b$ must be equal to $\mathsf{fib}(i+1)$. Now, from the expression for `c` and the expression $\mathsf{fib}(i+1) = \mathsf{fib}(i) + \mathsf{fib}(i-1)$ we easily obtain the condition for `a`: $a = \mathsf{i + fib(i-1)}$.

If we rewrite the for loop into an equivalent while loop, we'll get a loop invariant:

$$a = i + \mathsf{fib}(i-1) \wedge b = \mathsf{fib}(i) \wedge i \le n.$$

Here is how we can prove that the loop actually does the job:

```
{a = i + fib(i-1) /\ b = fib(i) /\ i <= n}
while i < n do
  {a = i + fib(i-1) /\ b = fib(i) /\ i < n}
  {a = i + fib(i-1) /\ b = fib(i) /\ b − i = fib(i) - i /\ i < n}
  c ← b − i
  {a = i + fib(i-1) /\ b = fib(i) /\ c = fib(i) - i /\ i < n}
  {a = i + fib(i-1) /\ c + a = (fib(i) - i) + (i + fib(i-1)) /\ c = fib(i) - i /\ i < n}
  {a = i + fib(i-1) /\ c + a = fib(i+1) /\ c = fib(i) - i /\ i < n}
  b ← c + a
  {a = i + fib(i-1) /\ b = fib(i+1) /\ c = fib(i) - i /\ i < n}
  {c + 2*i + 1 = fib(i) - i + 2*i + 1 /\ b = fib(i+1) /\ c = fib(i) - i /\ i < n}
  {c + 2*i + 1 = fib(i) + (i+1) /\ b = fib(i+1) /\ c = fib(i) - i /\ i < n}
  a ← c + 2*i + 1
  {a = (i+1) + fib(i) /\ b = fib(i+1) /\ c = fib(i) - i /\ i < n}
  {a = (i+1) + fib((i+1)-1) /\ b = fib(i+1) /\ (i+1)-1 < n}
  i ← i + 1
  {a = i + fib(i-1) /\ b = fib(i) /\ i <= n}
{a = i + fib(i-1) /\ b = fib(i) /\ i <= n /\ i >= n}
{a = i + fib(i-1) /\ b = fib(i) /\ i = n}
{b = fib(n)}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize I can freely use the Fibonacci function like this.

Comment: You are welcome! You can do it, because the *mathematical* function $\mathsf{fib}$ (which is used in the purely logical part of the whole thing) is not the same thing as the `fib` procedure that you define in your pseudocode. We proved that `fib` corresponds to the *ideal* $\mathsf{fib}$ function.